# Converting python string object to c char* using ctypes

Tags: c, string, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to send 2 strings from Python (3.2) to C using ctypes. This is a small part of my project on my Raspberry Pi. To test if the C function received the strings correctly, I place one of them in a text file.

**Python code**

```python
string1 = "my string 1"
string2 = "my string 2"

# create byte objects from the strings
b_string1 = string1.encode('utf-8')
b_string2 = string2.encode('utf-8')

# send strings to c function
my_c_function(ctypes.create_string_buffer(b_string1),
              ctypes.create_string_buffer(b_string2))
```

**C code**

```c
void my_c_function(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    // Test if string is correct
    FILE *fp = fopen("//home//pi//Desktop//out.txt", "w");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        fputs(str1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // Do something with strings..
}
```

**The problem**

Only the first letter of the string appears in the text file.

I've tried many ways to convert the Python string object with ctypes.

- ctypes.c_char_p
- ctypes.c_wchar_p
- ctypes.create_string_buffer

With these conversions I keep getting the error "wrong type" or "bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance".

I hope someone can tell me where it goes wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set `my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]`. Then, because the parameters are `const`, simply call it as `my_c_function(b_string1, b_string2)`.

Comment: FYI, a literal backslash character needs to be escaped as `"\\"`, but it's not required for a forward slash. It's just `"/home/pi/Desktop/out.txt"`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your reply. It works now, I totally forgot I had argtypes still set on c_wchar_p. About the slashes, I always get them mixed up.

Comment: Only use `buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bstr)` when the function modifies the string. It's equivalent to `buf = (ctypes.c_char * (len(bstr) + 1))();` `buf.value = bstr`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Thanks to Eryksun the solution:

**Python code**

```
string1 = "my string 1"
string2 = "my string 2"

# create byte objects from the strings
b_string1 = string1.encode('utf-8')
b_string2 = string2.encode('utf-8')

# send strings to c function
my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
my_c_function(b_string1, b_string2)
```

Comment: `my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes_char_p]` You mean `my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.char_p]` (notice `.` instead of `_`)?

Comment: Haha, after 5 years someone noticed or felt bothered to point it out. Thanks for it, I edited it in the answer.

Comment: You know, Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder!

Comment: `my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.char_p]` Do you mean `my_c_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]` ?

Answer (score 20):

I think you just need to use c_char_p() instead of create_string_buffer().

```
string1 = "my string 1"
string2 = "my string 2"

# create byte objects from the strings
b_string1 = string1.encode('utf-8')
b_string2 = string2.encode('utf-8')

# send strings to c function
my_c_function(ctypes.c_char_p(b_string1),
              ctypes.c_char_p(b_string2))
```

If you need mutable strings then use create_string_buffer() and cast those to c_char_p using ctypes.cast().

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [SWIG](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C)? I haven't tried it myself but here's what it would look like, without changing your C source:

```
/*mymodule.i*/

%module mymodule
extern void my_c_function(const char* str1, const char* str2);
```

This would make your Python source as simple as (skipping compilation):

```
import mymodule

string1 = "my string 1"
string2 = "my string 2"
my_c_function(string1, string2)
```

Note I'm not certain `.encode('utf-8')` is necessary if your source file is already UTF-8.

Comment: For Python 3 remember to use swig's `-py3` option. The wrapper encodes a Python 3 string as UTF-8, using [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8String`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8String) and then [`PyBytes_AsStringAndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_AsStringAndSize). Passing `bytes` raises a `TypeError`.