# Porting Python 2.7 code calling a C function to Python 3.4

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am trying to **call a C function from an `.so` file** from `Python 3.4`. I have made some necessary changes to make the `Python 2.7` code work with Python 3.4 but I am still running into a `Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault`.

The code is from this [Bitbucket hosted project](https://bitbucket.org/mavrik/slovene_lemmatizer). I have installed it via pip3 (`pip3 install Lemmagen`), which also created the .so file I am trying to use from Python3.

Here is the original Python2.7 code (the function where the call to C code happens) which runs fine with `python` from the command line.

```
def lemmatize(self, word):
    if (self._output_buffer_len < 2 * len(word)):
        self._output_buffer_len = 2 * len(word)
        self._output_buffer = create_string_buffer(self._output_buffer_len)

    is_unicode = isinstance(word, unicode)
    if is_unicode:
        word = word.encode('utf-8')

    self._lib.lem_lemmatize_word(word, self._output_buffer)
    return self._output_buffer.value.decode('utf-8') if is_unicode else self._output_buffer.value
```

And this is how I am trying to adapt it to Python3.4:

```
def lemmatize(self, word):
    if (self._output_buffer_len < 2 * len(word)):
        self._output_buffer_len = 2 * len(word)
        self._output_buffer = create_string_buffer(self._output_buffer_len)

    word = word.encode('utf-8')


    self._lib.lem_lemmatize_word(word, self._output_buffer) #SEGFAULT HERE!
    #return "HERE"
    return self._output_buffer.value.decode('utf-8')
```

I have removed the lines that check whether `word` is `unicode` or not, since Unicode is default in Python3.x. I am still 80% sure that is a **character encoding issue**. What encoding do I have to use to **pass on a string variable to the function call** `self._lib.lem_lemmatize_word(word, self._output_buffer)`? That is the exact line where the segmentation fault occurs:

Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

```
Current thread 0xb754b700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lemmagen/lemmatizer.py", line 66 in lemmatize
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have been trying to read up on my exact question (encoding type), but nothing I have found so far seems to solve this. I would appreciate some thoughtful information on this. Thank you.

*Thanks for whoever downvoted the question without a reason or any comment.*

Comment: It might be worth adding the fact that you are using ctypes, so you are calling a C function rather than a C++ function.

Comment: OK, I'll correct this.

Comment: @Pim @DrunkenMaster `lem_lemmatize_word` is actually defined as `extern "C"` in the sources, so calling it via ctypes shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I still don't see why the segmentation fault happens, I tried passing hard-coded `b'string'` and `u'string'`, too. They don't make a difference.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 yeah but the question states that it is a c++ function, which it isent.

Comment: Why is `self._output_buffer = create_string_buffer(self._output_buffer_len)` indented into the `if` block?

Comment: That's a very good question, but the Python2.7 version code is working fine with that, besides I have removed the indentation from the `if` block, but that does not tackle the segmentation fault being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the create_string_buffer function to create a char array before passing it to the function.

Something like this should work:

```
    import ctypes

class Lib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/pim/slovene_lemmatizer/bin/libLemmatizer.so')


def lemmatize(self, word):
    text = "text"
    output_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(text.encode())

    word_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(word.encode())

    self.lib.lem_lemmatize_word(word, output_buffer)

    print("test")

def main():
    lib = Lib()
    lib.lemmatize("test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this outputs:

`pim@pim-desktop:~/slovene_lemmatizer/bin$ python3 main.py
[ERROR] Language file for lemmatizer has to be loaded first!
test
pim@pim-desktop:~/slovene_lemmatizer/bin$`

Edit: I'm not 100% sure whether the usage of the 'raw' property here is correct though, but it works! 
Edit2: It does work without the raw property, updated the awnser

Comment: I am not sure about this, this modification gives me an `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'raw'` for the last code line in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo, now I have spotted it. But the function call still triggers a segmentation fault. :\

Comment: Do I have to set the `argtypes` explicitely, like in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127413/converting-python-string-object-to-c-char-using-ctypes

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I try to integrate this with lemmatizer.py and se if this works for me.

Comment: I was able to get through to the C function with your new code, but of course as the output (`[ERROR] Language file for lemmatizer has to be loaded first!`) shows, I have to deal with a C code bug.

Comment: Could you mark it as answered if it an answered  your question?